# Regex match all specific string or at least one

Tags: regex, perl

Here is my problem.

Test string:

```
abc.1.2.4.6.8.10.9.8.7.10.12345 = WORDS: "ABC|1A|CDE-FGH|password:FSSAD234SD2|cgap:234-34/23/23"
```

Regex:

```
9\.8\.7\.10\.(\d+) = (?:WORDS: )?"[^"]*(?:password:([A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+))
```

This will match `12345` and the password string `FSSAD234SD2`

But sometime I won't get the password string, so the test string would be as follows:

```
abc.1.3.5.7.9.11.9.8.7.10.12345 = ""
```

So I wanted to match at least `12345`

Online regex URL :

https://regex101.com/r/kQ3wT5/12 - Working fine.

https://regex101.com/r/kQ3wT5/13 - Not working.

Comment: Make the non capturing group optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex makes the password part optional. And captures in groups as you did.

**Regex:** `\.(\d+)\s*=(?:.*?password:([^|]*))?`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gpE5eK/1/)**

Comment: Thanks Rahul... :)  The second one not capturing the password string.

Comment: Go for the first one.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this regex :

```
'^(?:\w+\.)*(\d+) = (?:WORDS: )?"(?:.*\|password:([^\|]*).*)?"$'
```

If you need any precision, just ask !